# @BeanParam in Swagger with Resteasy 3.0 and Wildfly 8.0

Tags: java, maven, resteasy, wildfly, swagger

I'm trying to use Swagger to document my Rest API. I want to make use of @BeanParam annotation, however Swagger interprets the bean model as a single *body*. I've changed my swagger dependency to *swagger-jersey2-jaxrs_2.10* but that made Wildfly unable to start cause of **WELD-001408** error (as in first link below). I have read a lot of stuff, but nothing seems to solve my problem:

- https://developer.jboss.org/thread/240847
- https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/446
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/swagger-swaggersocket/K5TFkxIcRQs/A34nupqPTTcJ

I've tried by changing dependencies in my **pom.xml** according to linked threads, now it looks like this:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-gf-cdi</artifactId>
        <version>2.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.14</version>
    </dependency>
```

Moreover, I have a custom servlet for Swagger:

```
public class SwaggerServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4104485315753399385L;

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);

        BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
        beanConfig.setVersion("1.0.2");
        beanConfig.setBasePath("/CityAlertsWeb/service");
        beanConfig.setResourcePackage("pl.cityalerts.web.controllers");
        beanConfig.setScan(true);
        ClassReaders.setReader(new JerseyApiReader());
    }
}
```

Is there any way to make @BeanParam work in Swagger with Resteasy?
Should I add any other dependency?

With such a config I'm getting:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate ContextResolver
at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.registerProvider(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:1607)
at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.registerProvider(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:1310)
at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.registerProvider(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:1232)
at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.registerProvider(ResteasyDeployment.java:531)
at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.registration(ResteasyDeployment.java:338)
at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:241)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap.contextInitialized(ResteasyBootstrap.java:28)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:173)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:187)
... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find a public constructor for provider class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartProperties$Feature$MultiPartContextResolver
at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.createConstructorInjector(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:2184)
at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.createProviderInstance(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:2173)
at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.addContextResolver(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:1072)
at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.registerProvider(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:1601)
... 15 more
```

Thanks

Comment: Which version of swagger-core do you use? Also, have you tried excluding the jersey2 dependencies from the swagger-jersey2-jaxrs dependency? I imagine that would take away the WELD error.

Comment: I use the latest swagger (1.3.12). I updated pom.xml fragment above. How can I exclude jersey2? <exclusion>?</exclusion>

Comment: Yup, with the <exclusion> tag.

Comment: Yeah :), I meant what goes into exclusion tag?
<exclusion>       <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>  
<artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>  
</exclusion>?

Comment: You need to remove these: org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-multipart, org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server, org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client, org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common, org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core. I can't promise it won't break anything, but it's a start.

Comment: I can't promise it won't break anything - Well said :) Now I'm getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataParam which I excluded in org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-multipart :/. Arghh...

Comment: That's not surprising. It's now time for trial and error. Bring back that dependency, keep the rest out. See if you can either WELD error or CNFE error. Rinse, repeat.

Comment: I removed that exclusion (org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-multipart) and added it as a dependency instead (LOL) and it seems to start working. Hope it won't break much in the future. You can write something as an answer, so I can accept it -> 15pts for You. Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though RESTEasy 3.X has been officially released about a year and a half ago, it is still fairly uncommon, at least in our experience.

Swagger-core comes in several flavors, as a Play module, Servlet, and JAX-RS. When it comes to JAX-RS, there's a basic JAX-RS implementation for JAX-RS 1.X and then there are specific implementations for Jersey 1.X and Jersey 2.X.

The Jersey 1.X and 2.X implementations include support for file uploads in those libraries as, unfortunately, file uploads are not part of the JAX-RS specification and end up being implementation-specific.

However, another difference in the Jersey 2.X specific implementation is the support for JAX-RS 2.0, which includes the @BeanParam support. At the moment, there is no general-purpose JAX-RS 2.0 module.

From the original link, it seems there's a conflict between JBoss/WildFly and loading the Jersey dependencies, which the Jersey 2.X flavor pulls in. Based on the interactions in the comments, the solution is to exclude (`<exclusion>`) the org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-multipart dependency (which is indeed the one for file upload support) and adding it again manually in the main pom.xml. While not an elegant solution, it works as a workaround.

I would also suggest opening an issue about it in the swagger-core repository. I imagine JAX-RS 2.0 adoption will grow over time and we should give it proper support.